# Using Sumproduct to count how many are between date range in Excel

Tags: excel

The worksheet is here: https://dl.dropbox.com/u/3327208/Excel/PAERTO.xlsm

This is what I am trying to do, I am trying to "count" how many late jobs fall between a set of dates. As far as I remember, Sumproduct() is meant to do that, with some calculations of course thrown in.

I am using it like this: `=SUMPRODUCT((H23:H29>='Raw Data'!K2)*(H23:H29<='Raw Data'!K3))`

This formula **should** calculate the time between today, and a prior, and come back with a response. There should be 1. At least when this was posted. If not, then by tomorrow there will be none. And it should fall with a few others into the Within two Weeks range.

If someone could help me, it be greatly appreciated, because as far as I can tell this is not working the way it should... I am using Excel 2010 btw.

Comment: use SUM instead of SUMPRODUCT and validate the formula with CTRL + SHIFT + ENTER (array formula)

Comment: did, now getting a #VALUE! error.

Comment: I can't download the file at my workplace so I can't test but try =SUMPRODUCT(--(H23:H29>='Raw Data'!K2),--(H23:H29<='Raw Data'!K3))

Comment: Perfect, thanks, why did that work BTW?

Comment: If you make your post into an answer, I can mark it correct :)

Comment: There's no reason why your original formula wouldn't work, multiplying the two conditions will give you the same result as applying -- to each separately, although I thought K2 and K3 were dates, they don't look to be dates in the file.....In Excel 2010 for counting with multiple conditions (as here) COUNTIFS is normally preferable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I made changes to your workbook which can be downloaded here:
https://dl.dropbox.com/u/19599049/PAERTO_v2.xlsm

Because you are using Excel 2010 you can use the sumifs function which may be easier for you to work with and edit.

Added formulas in green cells (F5:F7)

Within a week: between day in 'Raw data' K2 and 7 days after
Within two weeks: between day in 'Raw data' K2 and 14 days after
Over two weeks: greater than 15 days after date from K2.